# SpeakProgress event handler for UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

How can I implement the equivalent of SpeakProgressEvent under UWP with SpeechSynthesis Class?  WPF/.NET has this event that I can hook onto, however, I'm confused about where they are hiding this feature in the UWP framework?  Does the .NET SpeakProgressEvent somehow map onto the MediaElement Event for UWP?

```
// NOTE: This is a windows 10 UWP Application (Not WPF/.NET)
using Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

//XAML: <MediaElement Name="mediaElement"/>

namespace App1
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        SpeechSynthesizer            synth;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

           // Doesn't Exist for UWP
            synth.SpeakProgress 
                 += new EventHandler<SpeakProgressEventArgs>
                    (synthesizer_SpeakProgress);

           // Doesn't Exist for UWP
            synth.SpeakStarted 
                 += new EventHandler<SpeakStartedEventArgs>
                    (synthesizer_SpeakStarted);

           // Doesn't Exist for UWP
            synth.SpeakCompleted 
                 += new EventHandler<SpeakCompletedEventArgs>
                    (synthesizer_SpeakCompleted);
        } //MainPage

        async Task Speak(string text)
        {
             SpeechSynthesisStream speech;
             speech = await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(text);
             mediaElement.SetSource(speech, speech.ContentType);
        }

        void synthesizer_SpeakProgress(
               object sender, SpeakProgressEventArgs e)
        {
            //show the synthesizer's current progress 
            //labelProgress.Content = e.Text;
            //SolidColorBrush highlightColor 
            //   = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
            //HighlightWordInRichTextBox(
            //    richTextBox1, e.Text, highlightColor);
        }


    } //class
} //namespace
```

Answer (score 3):

The difficulty here is that while the WPF `System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer` handles the audio output itself, the UWP `Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.SpeechSynthesizer` renders its result to a stream which can then be played by a `MediaElement`. On this way, most of the metadata is lost and the `MediaElement` has no clue about which word is currently being spoken, therefore it cannot provide an event similar to `SpeakProgress`.

**What you can do:**

First, ensure that all the metadata is maintained during stream synthesis by setting the following `SpeechSynthesizer` options:

```
synth = new SpeechSynthesizer
{
    Options = { IncludeWordBoundaryMetadata = true, IncludeSentenceBoundaryMetadata = true }
};
```

Note that the stream created by `synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(...)` is not a common `IRandomAccessStream`, but `SpeechSynthesisStream`, which offers some additional properties. For example, analyze the stream's `TimedMetadataTracks`: Typically, this will contain two items, one track that contains word boundary metadata and one that contains sentence boundary metadata.

The most interesting property of these `TimedMetadataTrack` objects will probably be `Cues`: This is a collection that contains elements of type `Windows.Media.Core.SpeechCue`, where each item corresponds to one sentence / word in the original text. Each item includes the following information:

1. character position (check the cue's `StartPositionInInput` and `EndPositionInInput` properties)
2. audio position (see the `StartTime` property)

**This means:**

Unfortunately, as mentioned before, there is no convenient event that notifies you about the progress, but you should be able to retrieve the necessary information about the current state / position through these metadata attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to get viseme information from the stream to animate a characters mouth.

One possible way to do it is use speech synthesis stream cues to create media markers. Then hook up to the media players marker reached event.

Use the CMU Dictionary to get phoneme information, then look up which viseme is associated with the phoneme.

While playing the media stream, the markers will be reached and you can then change the characters mouth shape.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is in this Sample File from Microsoft:

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis/cs/Scenario_SynthesizeTextBoundaries.xaml.cs